# Converting PeriodIndex to DateTimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I have a question regarding converting a tseries.period.PeriodIndex into a datetime.

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
               colors      country
time_month 

2010-09         xxx        xxx
2010-10         xxx        xxx
2010-11         xxx        xxx
...
```

time_month is the index.

```
type(df.index)
```

returns

```
class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'
```

When I try to use the df for a VAR analysis (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#vector-autoregressions-tsa-vector-ar),

```
VAR(mdata)
```

returns:

```
Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

So apparently, Period is not recognized as a datetime. Now, my question is how to convert the index (time_month) into a datetime the VAR analysis can work with?

```
df.index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

returns

```
cannot convert Int64Index->DatetimeIndex
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `to_timestamp` method of PeriodIndex for this:

```
In [25]: pidx = pd.period_range('2012-01-01', periods=10)

In [26]: pidx
Out[26]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
[2012-01-01, ..., 2012-01-10]
Length: 10, Freq: D

In [27]: pidx.to_timestamp()
Out[27]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-01, ..., 2012-01-10]
Length: 10, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

In older versions of Pandas the method was `to_datetime`

Comment: That solved it! For some reason, I must have had a syntax mistake before.

Comment: @Christopher BTW, in general, you should try to mark your questions as solved if an answer solves it (this also applies to your other questions)

Comment: Doesnot work. Cannot cast PeriodArray to dtype datetime64[ns]. If period array just cant be converted to anything, why was it invented?

Comment: The above code snippet *does* work, so best to ask a new question with your specific use case.

Comment: A follow up question: I wonder why `.dt.to_period('M').to_timestamp()` does not work. It says "TypeError: unsupported Type RangeIndex". Does it have to be 'D' for it to work?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the following to get exactly the same result.

```
idx.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

To convert back to period, you can do:

```
 idx.to_period(freq='D')
```

Comment: Cannot cast PeriodArray to dtype datetime64[ns]

Comment: Worked for me. Also doesn't give any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `periods.to_timestamp()`

```py
periods = ["2021Q1", "2021Q2", ...]
datetime_converted = periods.to_timestamp()
print (datetime_converted)
```

Otherwise

```py
# Easy and Simple
periods.astype("datetime64[ns]") # if object is a pandas dataframe
```