# Converting PeriodIndex to

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I had a dataframe that used `pd.Period` for the indexing, but later needed to use that data for plotting the x_axis in Bokeh.

```
df = return_data_with_multiindex()
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
type(df["calDate"][0]) # returns pandas._period.Period
```

Unfortunately Bokeh doesn't support period so I'm stuck on how to best convert it.

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Period' is not JSON serializable
```

[This answer didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394730/converting-periodindex-to-datetimeindex), as I still kept throwing type errors:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-287-8753a9594163> in <module>()
      1 #pd.to_datetime(df["calDate"], format='%Y-%m')
----> 2 df["calDate"].to_timestamp()
      3 df[["calDate","freq_hist_deseas","freq_futr","freq_tr12"]]
      4 #type(df["calDate"][0])

C:\ANACONDA36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in to_timestamp(self, freq, how, copy)
   2709             new_values = new_values.copy()
   2710 
-> 2711         new_index = self.index.to_timestamp(freq=freq, how=how)
   2712         return self._constructor(new_values,
   2713                                  index=new_index).__finalize__(self)

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_timestamp'
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's an example:

```
                  col1 col2 col3
i1 i2   pd.Period                                                                                   
x   y   2006-07    1   2   3
                   1   2   3
```

EDIT2: caldate

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
df["calDate"].head()

0   2006-07
1   2006-08
2   2006-09
3   2006-10
4   2006-11
Name: calDate, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you post the sample of dataframe you had.

Comment: How did you call `to_timestamp`?

Comment: `df["calDate"].to_timestamp()`

Comment: Your error traceback is telling you `calDate` is recognized as a `RangeIndex`.  What does `df.calDate.dtype` give you?

Comment: Can you add `df.calDate.head(5)`

Comment: `dtype == 'O'` which makes sense because `type(df["calDate"][0]) # returns pandas._period.Period`

Comment: @Tony check out my solution

Comment: It's probably feasible to serialize these. I just didn't know about them. Please open aa GH feature request issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to convert every period to timestamp so use lambda i.e

Example :

```
df['x']  = pd.period_range('7/1/2006', '11/1/2006', freq='M')

type(df['x'][0])
#pandas._libs.period.Period

df['x'].apply(lambda x : x.to_timestamp())
```

Output:

```
0   2006-07-01
1   2006-08-01
2   2006-09-01
3   2006-10-01
4   2006-11-01
Name: x, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```