# Python: error in plotting data created with `period_range` (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a problem in plotting time series data, created using pandas `date_range` and `period_range`. The former works, but the latter does not. To illustrate the problem, consider the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# random numbers
N = 100
z = np.random.randn(N)
ts = pd.DataFrame({'Y': z, 'X': np.cumsum(z)})

# 'date_range' is used
month_date = pd.date_range('1978-02', periods=N, freq='M')
df_date = ts.set_index(month_date)

# 'period_range' is used
month_period = pd.period_range('1978-02', periods=N, freq='M')
df_period = ts.set_index(month_period)

# plot
plt.plot(df_date);plt.show()
plt.plot(df_period);plt.show()
```

`plt.plot(df_date)` gives a nice figure, whereas `plt.plot(df_period)` generates the following error, which I do not understand:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Is this an expected result? What am I missing here?

BTW, `df_date.plot()` and `df_period.plot()` both work fine, causing no problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexes of the two dateframes are of different type:

```
print(type(df_date))    # pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
print(type(df_period))  # pandas.core.indexes.period.PeriodIndex
```

Matplotlib does not know how to plot a `PeriodIndex`.

You may [convert the `PeriodIndex` to a `DatetimeIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394730/converting-periodindex-to-datetimeindex) and plot that one instead,

```
plt.plot(df_period.to_timestamp())
```